# Android command-line testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm attempting to set up the android testing framework.

I have a project in `~/boldapp/BOLDApp/`

I decided I should have by test project in `~/boldapp/BOLDApp/tests` as described in http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects

I have done the following as per http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html :

I run `android create test-project -m ../ -n BOLDAppTest -p tests`

I now want to run the Instrumentation test case `MainActivityTest.java` that was generated.

When I run `ant run-tests`, as suggested, I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "run-tests" does not exist in the project "BOLDAppTest".
```

When I alternatively run `ant test` part of the output is:

```
test:
     [echo] Running tests ...
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{au.edu.unimelb.boldapp.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
     [exec] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
     [exec] android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED:
```

I get the same error as above when I run `adb shell am instrument -w au.edu.unimelb.boldapp.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`:

as well as when I run:

`adb shell am instrument -w au.edu.unimelb.boldapp/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

How do I run the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must.haven't installed test apk successfully in your device. you can check by execute adb shell "pm list instrumentation".

Comment: I get no output when I run adb shell pm list instrumentation. I didn't realise I needed a device. When I run "ant emma debug install test" it works.

Comment: Congratulations. But do you know what does emma means for?